# Cadastro de usuários com CPF ou CNPJ Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, validação

Como faço a validação personalizada do cadastro de usuários do `Laravel` no `auth` padrão usando `php artisan make:auth`?

Preciso da seguintes cláusula ***É obrigatório inserir o campo CPF ou CNPJ***.

Encontrei a validação do cadastro, mas, gostaria de adicionar essa clausula?

```
return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
```

Comment: Qual é a dúvida? não é só inserir os dados de validação no Validator e pronto?

Comment: Como uso conectivo OU ? Na validação, para aceitar apenas um OU outro

Answer (score 1):

Dê uma olhada na documentação:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation

**required_with:foo,bar,...**
The field under validation must be present and not empty only if any of the other specified fields are present.

**required_with_all:foo,bar,...**
The field under validation must be present and not empty only if all of the other specified fields are present.

**required_without:foo,bar,...**
The field under validation must be present and not empty only when any of the other specified fields are not present.

**required_without_all:foo,bar,...**
The field under validation must be present and not empty only when all of the other specified fields are not present.

Talvez assim funcione (não testei)

```
$validator = \Validator::make(["cnpj"=>123, "cpf"=>123],[
        "cpf"   => "required_without_all:cnpj",
        "cnpj"  => "required_without_all:cpf"
    ]);
```

Comment: Eu recebo a seguinte mensagem usando da forma que você me passou, testei todos os outros métodos mas não consegui ainda!

<code>

Comment: Eu recebo a seguinte mensagem usando da forma que você me passou, testei todos os outros métodos mas não consegui ainda!
O campo cnpj não é um CNPJ válido
É pq no campo de cnpj e cpf eu tenho a validação personalizada de cnpj e cpf 
<code>
'cpf' => '|cpf|required_if:cnpj,0|unique:clientes,cpf',
            'cnpj' => '|cnpj|required_if:cpf,0|unique:clientes,cnpj',
</code>